# Assume there are $n$ people and a successful derangement has been drawn. If $1$ drew $2$, what is the probability that $2$ drew $1$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, derangements

Assume there are $n$ people and a successful derangement has been drawn. If $1$ drew $2$, what is the probability that $2$ drew $1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Assume there are $n$ people, and a successful [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) has been drawn. If $1$ drew $2$, what is the probability that $2$ drew $1$?

Note that $*$ denotes the person to be deranged.

Considering the venn diagram,

[image]
\begin{align*}
P(21**\cdots|*1**\cdots)&=\frac{N(21**\cdots)}{N(*1**\cdots)}\\
\end{align*}

### METHOD $1$

where, by the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle),
\begin{align*}
N(21**\cdots)&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(-1)^k{n-2\choose k}(n-2-k)!=(n-2)!\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}=!(n-2)\\
N(*1**\cdots)&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(-1)^k{n-2\choose k}(n-1-k)!=(n-1)[!(n-2)]+(n-2)[!(n-3)]=\frac{!n}{n-1}\\
\end{align*}
after rigorous simplification including breaking the summation into two.

---

### METHOD $2$

In a simpler method, since $m$ persons can be deranged in $!m=m!\left(\frac1{2!}-\frac1{3!}+\cdots+(-1)^m\right)$ ways,
\begin{align*}
N(21**\cdots)&=!(n-2)\\
N(*1**\cdots)&=\frac{!n}{n-1}\\
\end{align*}
Explanation for $N(*1**\cdots)=\frac{!n}{n-1}$:

In deranging all $n$ persons, there are $n-1$ possible places $1$ could have been moved to, for the derangement method doesn't count the place of $1$. Hence, there are $\frac{!n}{n-1}$ ways of deranging $n$ persons such that $1$ moves to the place of $2$ and not to that of $3,4,\ldots n$.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

How many possibilities are there in that situation for persons $3,4,\dots,n$?

Be aware that each of them must be placed on a spot that differs from their original spot and that they cannot be placed on the spots 1 and 2. So again we recognize the possibilities as derangements.

Comment: In my former (and deleted) comment something was wrong. It should be $$P(\sigma(2)=1\mid\sigma(1)=2)=P(\sigma(2)=1,\sigma(1)=2)/P(\sigma(1)=2)$$Here the numerator takes value $!(n-2)/!n$ and that is actually my hint in the answer. The denominator takes value $1/(n-1)$ because there are $n-1$ equiprobable possiblities for $\sigma(1)$

Comment: @drhab I still don't get it. Where did you arrive at $P=\frac 13$ for $n=4$ and $P=\frac 2{11}$ for $n=5$ with your formulae? I hope my numbers are correct.

Comment: For $n=4$ there are exactly $3$ derangements with $1$ on second spot: $2143,4123,3142$. Exactly one of them has $2$ on first spot (2143 that is). So the probability on that is $\frac13$.

Comment: @SameerBaheti To be clear... It looks like you are confusing notation.  Note the difference between $n!$ where the exclamation point is to the *right* and $!n$ where the exclamation point is to the *left*.  The value $\dfrac{(n-2)!}{n!}$ is not the same as the value $\dfrac{!(n-2)}{!n}$.  Exclamation points on the right like $n!$ represent factorials, counting the total number of permutations of $n$ elements.  Exclamation points on the *left* like $!n$ represent the total number of *derangements* on $n$ elements.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ahh.. That could be the point! I hope you are right. Thank you.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yeah! I just looked derangement up at Wikipedia to be sure. I have never come across this notation.